# Replacing multiple values in matrix at once in R

Tags: r, vector, replace, na

I have a big preference matrix P with 100+ rows of patients and 100+ columns of kidney preferences. I have to allocate these kidneys to the patients in some way. After I found the first subset of allocations I would like to 1. remove the patients from the patients to be considered and 2. to replace the kidneys that have been allocated to NA in the preference matrix. I loop this procedure multiple times. I know how to do 1. but when I try to do 2. only a few of the numbers I want to have changed to NA actually change.

After I finished my loop I'd have a vector of the kidneys that are being allocated as follows:

```
taken= c(94, 42, 72, 12, 45, 68, 10, 100, 98)
```

I then try to replace these numbers in the preference matrix P with NA by using:

```
P[P==taken]=NA
```

But I still see some of the values that I try to replace in the matrix. Any advice?

Comment: `P[P %in% taken] = NA`? `==` can only compare with one value, not a vector of values. `%in%` will look for the value in the whole vector `taken`.

Comment: I've tried this but this unfortunately also leaves all original values in the matrix.

Comment: You can loop through "taken" and then your code should work.

Comment: That worked @JacobJacox. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `apply`:

```
a=matrix(92:100,nrow = 3,ncol = 3)
taken= c(94, 42, 72, 12, 45, 68, 10, 100, 98)
```

`a` before `NA`

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   92   95   98
[2,]   93   96   99
[3,]   94   97  100

a[apply(a,1,function(x) (x%in%taken))]=NA
```

`a` after `NA`

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   92   95   NA
[2,]   93   96   99
[3,]   NA   97   NA
```

Answer (score 0):

No sure I understand the question, but this might answer it.

```r
# Generate preference matrix 
P <-  matrix(1:100,nrow = 10)

P
#>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#>  [1,]    1   11   21   31   41   51   61   71   81    91
#>  [2,]    2   12   22   32   42   52   62   72   82    92
#>  [3,]    3   13   23   33   43   53   63   73   83    93
#>  [4,]    4   14   24   34   44   54   64   74   84    94
#>  [5,]    5   15   25   35   45   55   65   75   85    95
#>  [6,]    6   16   26   36   46   56   66   76   86    96
#>  [7,]    7   17   27   37   47   57   67   77   87    97
#>  [8,]    8   18   28   38   48   58   68   78   88    98
#>  [9,]    9   19   29   39   49   59   69   79   89    99
#> [10,]   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90   100

# Removed for example with smaller matrix
taken= c(1,2,5, 10)

# Set taken rows to NA
P[taken,1:dim(P)[2]] = NA

P
#>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#>  [1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
#>  [2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
#>  [3,]    3   13   23   33   43   53   63   73   83    93
#>  [4,]    4   14   24   34   44   54   64   74   84    94
#>  [5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
#>  [6,]    6   16   26   36   46   56   66   76   86    96
#>  [7,]    7   17   27   37   47   57   67   77   87    97
#>  [8,]    8   18   28   38   48   58   68   78   88    98
#>  [9,]    9   19   29   39   49   59   69   79   89    99
#> [10,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
```